# Why doesn't the menu provider add the menu to the toolbar?

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently started working with Android Studio. I've been trying to get the Menu Provider to work for two days. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much!
this is my activity.xml toolbar

```
`<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/home_top_bar"
                    style="@style/Widget.App.Toolbar.Centered"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:menu="@menu/empty_menu"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

I tried either assigning a menu or not.

this is my activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
private lateinit var navController: NavController
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.home_nav_controller) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

    binding.homeTopBar.apply {
        setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

}

this is fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()

        menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu)
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                when(menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.account -> {
                        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_userFragment)
                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.join_game -> {
                        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_joinGameFragment)
                        return true
                    } else -> return false
                }
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)


        binding.apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            //viewModel = sharedViewModel
            homeFragment = this@HomeFragment
        }
    }

    fun newGame() {
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_newGameFragment)
    }
}
```

I also tried to make the fragment inherit the menu provider interface but I got the same result.

And theme is Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: Can you share the activity class that this fragment is attached to, as well as what theme the activity is using?

Comment: Hi! Might be unrelated but the Coordinator layout must be the root of your activity layout and must match our parent both in width and height.  Coordinator layout is used for animations. If you do not wish for such animations then you can use a regular constraint layout as your root.

Comment: Fragments are like articles in a newspaper. You are trying to add a menu to a fragment that has not been setup with a toolbar. Are you trying to add a menu to your activity's toolbar?

Comment: hiii, yes i'm trying to add a menu to activity's toolbar, but this code don't work although i put a menu

Answer (score 0):

Your code in fragment seems fine. Try making these changes in your activity

> HomeActivity

```
// Set your toolbar
setSupportActionBar(binding.homeTopBar)

// Set your nav host
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.home_nav_controller) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

// Set up the integration between the NavController and the app's action bar
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

// Set up the app bar with the NavController and configure with appBarConfiguration
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: This is not related to your problem but you can also set your binding like so,
binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)